# html canvas, rotate canvas around center with mousedown only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

Sorry if this is duplication very obviously. Requesting, flag after answer first.. I have my hair out of my head..

Why is nothing all here? Please help the new to .html canvas and .js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="r" width="300" height="150" style="border:solid></canvas>

<script>
var ctx=document.getElementById("r").getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(50,20,100,50);

function roc(){//rotate on click
ctx.translate(r.width/2,r.height/2);
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
}r.addEventListener("mousedown",roc)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of glitches in your code:

- you have a reference to the context (ctx) but you also need a reference to the canvas (r)
- existing rectangles cannot be moved or rotated (they are just pixels painted on the canvas)
- to move/rotate, you should erase the canvas and redraw the rect in its new rotation

Here's annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GMtPT/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get reference variables to both the canvas and the canvas-context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("r");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // this determines how much the canvas is rotated
    var rotation=0;

    // call roc to draw the rectangle the first time
    roc();

    function roc(){
        // clear the canvas in preparation for new drawings
        // NOTE: you can't move/rotate existing drawings!
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // save the context in its untranslated unrotated state
        ctx.save();

        // translate to center canvas
        // (this means the origin [0,0] will be at center canvas
        ctx.translate(r.width/2,r.height/2);

        // increase the rotation by 20 more degrees
        rotation+=20*Math.PI/180;

        // rotate the canvas by 20 degrees
        ctx.rotate(rotation);

        // draw a rectangle
        // the rectangle will be rotated by [rotation] degrees
        // Note: [0,0] is center canvas so we fillRect with x,y offset by 1/2 width & height
        // because fillRect positions the top-left part of the rectangle at x,y
        var rectWidth=100;
        var rectHeight=50;
        ctx.fillRect(-rectWidth/2,-rectHeight/2,rectWidth,rectHeight);

        // restore the context to its unrotated state 
        ctx.restore();
    }


    // listen for mousedown and call roc
    r.addEventListener("mousedown",roc)


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="r" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your translate is taking your origin off the screen in one click... you need to do something like this... notice the ctx.save() and ctx.restore() that will reset your origin each time.

```
function roc(){//rotate on click
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,r.width,r.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(r.width/2,r.height/2);
    rotate+=10;
    ctx.rotate(rotate*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.fillRect(-50,-25,100,50);
    ctx.restore();
}
roc();
r.addEventListener("mousedown",roc)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8UCc/